# Compare integers stored as Strings in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, type-conversion, aggregation-framework

In the below collection, column "qty" holds the integer values but the datatype is string.

I want to compare the "qty" field with an integer in the aggregate and "warehouse" field with a string "A". ("qty" > 2 and "warehouse" = "A")

[Can't change the datatype in the collection to integer as huge dependency is present]

**Edit** : *Need to retrieve all the columns and all the documents matching the criteria.*

**Query** : *getting improper results*

```
db.runCommand(
    {
        aggregate: "products", pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    instock: {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            warehouse: "A",
                            qty: { $gt: "2" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            { $project: { _id: 0 } }],
        cursor: { batchSize: 200 }
    });
```

**Result** : *not getting documents where item = journal though it satisfies the conditions*

```
/* 1 */
{
    "item" : "paper",
    "instock" : [
        {
            "warehouse" : "A",
            "qty" : "60"
        },
        {
            "warehouse" : "B",
            "qty" : "15"
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "item" : "planner",
    "instock" : [
        {
            "warehouse" : "A",
            "qty" : "22"
        },
        {
            "warehouse" : "B",
            "qty" : "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Products Collection**

```
[
    {
        "item": "journal",
        "instock": [
            {
                "warehouse": "A",
                "qty": "11"
            },
            {
                "warehouse": "C",
                "qty": "15"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item": "paper",
        "instock": [
            {
                "warehouse": "A",
                "qty": "60"
            },
            {
                "warehouse": "B",
                "qty": "15"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item": "planner",
        "instock": [
            {
                "warehouse": "A",
                "qty": "22"
            },
            {
                "warehouse": "B",
                "qty": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Getting improper results as greater than operator in this case is working lexicographically but it should work like integers. Though I tried converting that to double but I am getting no results.

**Query with $convert to double** : *no result*

```
db.runCommand(
    {
        aggregate: "products", pipeline: [
            //{ $match: { "item": { $in: ["planner", "paper","journal"] } } },
            {
                $match: {
                    instock: {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            warehouse: "A",
                            qty: {
                                $gt: [
                                    {$convert:{ input: "$qty", to: "double" }}, 5]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            { $project: { _id: 0 } }],
        cursor: { batchSize: 200 }
    });
```

Comment: why are you running your queries as like this :: `db.runCommand` on admin, you can just run queries on database-collection rather than what you're doing cause usually we don't do that way, also you need not to do any conversion in this case plus no need to use aggregation framework for this simple task just use `.find()` :-)

Comment: User creates the query graphically on UI, he selects fields and applies operators and filters on that..

Comment: what does it has to do with you executing queries on a collection vs passing runCommands ?

Comment: These are related to data fabric screens. collection name and the columns are dynamic. So we are creating the custom query with all the complex business rules and executing that in Mongodb with the help of db.runCommand. Please suggest if there is a better approach to this.

Comment: where are you executing your queries thru code or thru shell ?

Comment: Executing the query through C# Mongo driver with the help of Db.runCommand method.

Comment: It's ok I've updated my query, did you get a chance to execute it as you would normally do using C# ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to retain objects has criteria :

```
db.runCommand(
    {
        aggregate: "products", pipeline: [
            { $match: { 'instock.warehouse': 'A' } },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    instockCheck: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$instock', as: 'each', cond: {
                                $and: [{ $gt: [{ $toInt: '$$each.qty' }, 2] },
                                { $eq: ['$$each.warehouse', 'A'] }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, { $match: { instockCheck: { $gt: [] } } }, { $project: { instockCheck: 0, _id: 0 } }],
        cursor: { batchSize: 200 }
   });
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SR7OAXXHaPK)

Comment: Not working as expected, because the greater than operator work Lexicographically with strings. Later in the API, the exact query is formed in plain string and gets executed on the database using db.runCommand

Comment: @siddhantsrivastava  : Can you give me an example of where it’s failing? I would say strings with alphanumeric characters are different than strings with just numbers!!

Comment: @siddhantsrivastava : Ok if you’re getting filters as string and using runCommands to directly execute string as query is ok but in general most apps doesn’t do that way but not a problem but do you still think comparison of string numbers is not working for you?

Comment: It's not fetching the document where item = Journal, though it satisfies the criteria.

Comment: @siddhantsrivastava : sorry that was my bad, updated answer :-)

Comment: Whoami I checked with my actual solution. But there is a very minor issue as $filter creates a subset of an array and the output expects all the products which match the conditions instock.qty > 5 and instock.warehouse = 'A'.

So, if a product matches the condition then instead of returning subset of instock array we should return the full instock array of that product.

Comment: @siddhantsrivastava : I've updated query, you can try now !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$instock"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$instock.warehouse",
              "A"
            ]
          },
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $toInt: "$instock.qty"
              },
              2
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      item: {
        $first: "$item"
      },
      instock: {
        $push: "$instock"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4t4mA3KuRNS)

Comment: Using $unwind I can convert the string field to Int and later apply the greater than operator to filter out the result. 


But while retrieving the result, we serialize i to the product data Model, Product data model expects an array of instock.
So here is another issue as when instock is no longer array we cannot serialize it to the model.


So, if a product matches the condition then instead of subset of instock array we should return the full instock array of that product.

Comment: We are using C# Mongo Driver to execute the query with the help of db.runCommand method. Changing the data Model will not be possible as existing code will break.

Comment: @siddhantsrivastava Try it please, if MonogDB changes datatype during execution, but return the result as your data model, C# driver will process it correctly